# Relation between $[L \cap M : K \cap M]$ and $[L : K]$, and the Wantzel theorem

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction

The well-known Gauß-Wantzel Theorem states that a real number $x$ can be constructed using straightedge and compass *only if* the minimal polynomial of $x$ (over the field $\mathbf Q$) has degree of form $2^n$, $n \in \mathbf N$.

Is is a corollary of a more general theorem, named “Wantzel Theorem” in French, which (under the form I know) states that :

> **Wantzel Theorem**
>
> The real number $x$ can be constructed using straightedge and compass *if and only if* there exists a sequence of commutative fields $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset … \subset L_n$ such that:
>
> 1. $L_0 = \mathbf Q$
> 2. $x \in L_n$
> 3. For all $i = 1, ..., n$, $[L_i : L_{i-1}] = 2$

---

I wonder whether in the latter theorem, condition 2 could be replaced by $L_n = \mathbf Q[x]$.

Of course, this constraint 2′ implies constraint 2, so we have one implication.

To get the other implication, I assume I have a sequence $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset … \subset L_n$ matching conditions 1, 2 and 3, and I set for $i = 0, ..., n$, $L'_i = L_i \cap \mathbf Q[x]$. Then I need to prove that for $i=1, ...,n$, $[L'_i : L'_{i-1}] \le 2$.

My question is: is the latter statement true?

---

In a more general way, **if $L$ is a finite extension of field $K$, and $M$ is another field, what can we say about $[L \cap M : K \cap M]$**?

Thanks in advance!